# How to attach bytebuddy agent to the dynamic class, especially, when dynamic class are loaded from signed jar file

Tags: byte-buddy, javaagents, classloading

I tried attach bytebuddy agent to the old applet. In some runtime stage, that old applet receives a signed jar file from the other host and load them dynamically.
The problem is that the agent doesn't work in that dynamic loading stage. I think 
 that in such a case, Rafael Winterhalter told that `with(ProtectionDomain)` and `AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice` are just solution. But how to apply them? I tried as far as possible I can to get nothing. And there are no usecase on the web.  Anyone help me.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A Java agent should be notified on any class loading activity. With applets, there is however a chance that a security manager blocks the instrumentation if Byte Buddy uses any privileged action without having it permitted.

When using advice, there should not be any difference wether a jar is loaded at runtime or if the application is an applet. Do you get any error message? Register an `AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut()` listener to debug such problems.